# Magento 2 hide / show editor not working

Tags: magento2, tinymce

Here is the pic the showing the tinyMCE is not showing and the button is not work

[image]

The browser console does not have any exception or error is showing, anyone know what is the problem?

Remarks tested on (xampp+windows and nginx+php7)

Comment: I had this problem recently in Firefox. Switching to chrome solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a known Magento js bug, there is a fix for it but not deployed in the current version so you would need to patch Magento:

1. the fix url is: `https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/3524943ac6544ee969480536ef6f0cd1a29b0b56.patch`  ( just the github issue sollution with .patch extension added ) save the content of the patch into a file ex: `vendor_patches/MAGETWO-57675-Base.diff` in the root of magento where `vendor_patches` is an directory created for patches
2. and you can create a patch as follows:
   Add to your composer.json ( in the root of magento )

   {

   ```
   "require": {
       "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.4.0",
   },

   "extra": {
       "patches": {
           ""magento/magento2-base": {
               "[PATCH] MAGETWO-57675: [GITHUB] WYSIWYG editor does not show. #6222": "vendor_patches/MAGETWO-57675-Base.diff"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Run `composer update` in the root of your magento

Comment: this work for me , thx

Answer (score 0):

Check on this configuration:

**Store > Configuration > General > Content Management > Enable wysiwyg.**

But if is enabled it is taking time to load, but I do this to optimize and to load normally:

- Increase the **memory_limit** and **max_execution_time** on .htaccess or NGINX config.
- If don't is developing, enable the cache.
- Run the deploy of the static files again.
- Give permit to folders `var/` and `pub/static`.
- But because of the Knockout, I wait to load this feature.

Comment: When JS Bundling and CSS minification are enabled. I have the issue where it does not display.  However, I get a bunch of JS errors of Failed to load: /themes/advanced/editor_template.js, /back/edit//langs/en.js and 50 or so similiar ones.  Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked in my case:

Store > Configuration > General > Content Management > WYSIWYG Editor
Select tinymce 3 (deprected)

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to store->configuration→general→content management→enable wysiwyg edit uncheck checkbox and save configurations.
2. Remove pub/static ,var/generation ,var/cache,var/view_preprocessed
3. deploy static content

Comment: if you work on the development enviornment it is not a sollution to deploy static content since you work with symlinks